# Handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null) and main looper

Tags: android

In the onDestory of a fragment, I put the code to clean up all pending runnables I started using Handler.postDelayed.

```
mUiHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
```

I have a question here. Is it safe to call mUiHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);? What I understand is, Android does all UI operations, like UI layout, UI rendering, component lifecycles (onCreate, onPause, onResume) in main looper. Do I understand it correctly? Then, when I call mUiHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null) in a fragment, will it mess up or clean up all the Android system UI operations in the message queue in main looper, since there is only one message queue in main looper.

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That will only remove messages and callbacks that have been posted *to that specific Handler*. It will not remove anything else, so yes, that's safe to do. :)

EDIT: It does share the `Queue` with the `Looper`, but it checks against the message target to make sure it came from the same `Handler` before removing. From `MessageQueue.java`:

```
void removeCallbacksAndMessages(Handler h, Object object) {
    if (h == null) {
        return;
    }

    synchronized (this) {
        Message p = mMessages;

        // Remove all messages at front.
        while (p != null && p.target == h
                && (object == null || p.obj == object)) {
            Message n = p.next;
            mMessages = n;
            p.recycle();
            p = n;
        }

        ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks kcoppock. But I am still confused. "Each Handler instance is associated with a single thread and that thread's message queue." Each thread should have one message queue. Right? My mUiHandler is associated with main thread, so per the doc, it will share the same message queue with other handlers on UI threads. Did I miss anything?

Comment: I got it. I looked at the source code. It does 'p.target == h' check in removeCallbacksAndMessages. So as you said, it only removes messages and callbacks that have been posted to that specific Handler. Thanks!

Comment: Was just about to post that, haha. :) Glad you found it!