# The effects of firing off a runnable multiple times using a Handler

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler, runnable

I have simple runnable like so

```
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        someVariable = true;
    }
};
```

I use it with a Handler and delay like this

```
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 60000);
```

if this functionality gets spammed and the above is called repeatedly it adds runnable multiple times to the message queue.

if this is the case is there away to check if there is one in the message queue first before adding another?

Comment: I don't know Android, so I don't know whether there is a better way, but if not, then you could use a global `AtomicInteger` to keep your own count of how many instances are in the queue.  The first line of your `run()` method could decrement the count, and you could increment it every time you `postDelayed(...)`.  (Or not, if the count already is too high.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi the way I do is to remove the messages and callbacks after my handler runs once. A simple example of my code would be

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d("runnable", "handler invoked just once");
            handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        }
    };

    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000);
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000); // demo: if this is called multiple times my runnable code wont run
```

Comment: what does this comment mean // demo: if this is called multiple times my runnable code wont run

Comment: Hi Rob, handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null); inside runnable removes the handlers callback and messages from Message Queue. When my handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000) is spammed multiple times, the code inside runnable which is someVariable = true for you would not be executed more than once. Comment :demo demonstrates handler being called twice while runnable code executes just once.

Comment: Thank you Rishabh, just to clarify will this only remove messages and callbacks create using this handler, any other handlers created through the app wont be effected? or this a main queue for all messages?

Comment: It removes messages and callbacks that are creating by the handler calling removeCallbacksAndMessages() function, not other handlers. So its safe to use. Hopefully this thread helps you Rob https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26126474/handler-removecallbacksandmessagesnull-and-main-looper

Comment: Thanks Rishabh :-)